# Why do Ultimate Guitar pro tabs sound artificial?

Tags: guitar

I'm new to playing guitar and wanted to learn guitar online. So I bought a subscription for Ultimate Guitar pro to start learning. But all the acoustic songs on the pro sound computerized. Is that sound/notes only for representation and once I play the same on my acoustic guitar, will it sound better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "play" the tabs on the website, the sound you are hearing is generated by a music engine, just to represent the notes shown.

When you play the same tabs on an actual guitar it will sound natural.